# inherit an service from an base class in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below service and I am trying to inherit my service with an base class so I can put all the constant option data in the base class,

> Service class

```
import { BaseNotification } from './baseNotification';
declare let toastr: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService extends BaseNotification
{

  constructor() {
    super();
    toastr.options =  this.options;
   }

  success(message: string, title?: string): void {
    toastr.success(message, title);
  }
```

> BaseNotification Class

```
export class BaseNotification {
    options = {};
    constructor(){
        this.options = {
            "closeButton": true,
            "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
            "preventDuplicates": false,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "1000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
          }
    }
}
```

But it does not recognize baseclass.  I do not want to create an seperate child Service.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is declare statement above? Do you want to initialize the base class value to sub class global variable?

Comment: this is just to satisfy TS transpiler to not throw error while static type checking as this toastr variable is avaliable only on runtime.

Comment: _"But it does not recognize baseclass"_ Elaborate. What is the expectation?

Answer (score 0):

am not sure about declare let statement outside of class, but if you want to initialize super class constants to sub class, you can create instance variable and initialize to it like below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService extends BaseNotification
{

public toastr: any;

  constructor() {
    super();
    toastr =  this.options;
   }

-----
------

}
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ktku5i) example

Comment: I tried the same but some how it seems,  angular does not let us inherit an base class from an service.

Comment: @Akash Updated answer with stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

maybe toastr whould be declared in base class, and the notificationService implements the logic.

> @Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) export class NotificationService
> extends BaseNotification {
>
> constructor(toastr: ToastrService) {
> super(toastr);
> }
>
> success(message, title) {
> return super.toastr.success(message, title);
> }
>
> }